# python: how can I create something which generates all possible combinations in a form of tuples for integers from A and B

Tags: python, tuples, range, combinations, generate

## Question:

```
# Let A= {m | m is an integer satisfying 0 < m < 13} and 
# B = {n | n is an integer satisfying 7 < n < 23}. 

# I'm trying to generate all possible combinations of (A,B).
For example:

A= (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
B =(7,8,9,10,11...)

Combination = (1,7),(1,8)(1,9)....(2,7),(2,8),(2,9).... and so forth
```

-I was thinking of using a for loop but could not seem to manage to get it working.

Comment: You should use `itertools.product`, read on it a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity you could just use :

```
for a in A:
  for b in B:
    print((a,b,))
```

or

```
combinations = [(a,b,) for a in A for b in B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.product`, as in the below code:

```
import itertools
out = itertools.product(A, B)
```